# Consulta con suma filtrada por fecha SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

tengo una BD que almacena las notas de venta y existencias de productos, entre otras cosas, necesito realizar una consulta que me arroje la disponibilidad de cada producto en cada bodega, junto con la cantidad vendida del mismo en determinado rango de fecha, asi la cantidad vendida sea 0, he estado probando de diferentes formas, sin exito... cualquier orientación seria bienvenida.
anexo modelo E-R de las tablas

este script es el ultimo que he probado

Añado un archivo de excel con el resultado deseado, solo que alli solo esta listada 1 sucursal, necesito que en la consulta salgan todas

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spRotacionFinal]
@fi date,
@ff date

as
declare @inicio date,@final date
set @inicio=@fi
set @final=@ff
BEGIN
with

Resumen as (
select EXISTENCIAS.id_producto, sum(DETALLE_NOTAVENTA.cantidad) Vendido

  from EXISTENCIAS
       inner join DETALLE_NOTAVENTA on DETALLE_NOTAVENTA.id_producto = EXISTENCIAS.id_producto
       Inner join NOTA_VENTAS on NOTA_VENTAS.id_nota=DETALLE_NOTAVENTA.id_nota
WHERE ((convert (date,fecha,1)>=@fi) and convert (date,fecha,1) <=@ff)
 group by EXISTENCIAS.id_producto,  NOTA_VENTAS.id_bodega
)

select  EXISTENCIAS.id_producto as codigo,
        Productos.nombre as descripcion,
        EXISTENCIAS.id_local ,
        BODEGAS.nombre as bodega,
        EXISTENCIAS.Disponible as disponible,
        @fi as inicio,
        @ff as final,
        coalesce(Resumen.Vendido, 0) Vendido
  from EXISTENCIAS
       left join Resumen on Resumen.id_producto = EXISTENCIAS.id_producto
       Inner Join BODEGAS on BODEGAS.Id_bodega = EXISTENCIAS.id_local
       INNER JOIN PRODUCTOS on PRODUCTOS.id_producto=EXISTENCIAS.id_producto
order by EXISTENCIAS.id_producto,EXISTENCIAS.id_local
END
```

pero duplica los códigos, asigna los mismos valores de suma a las 3 sucursales que salen en el reporte, y algunos codigos salen duplicados
[Diagrama E-R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcfK.png)

[image: Consulta Obtenida]

[image: Resultado Deseado, incluyendo todas las sucursales, ya que alli solo se muestra 1]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "he probado de varias formas sin éxito" debería ir acompañado de esas consultas que probaste y los errores que obtuviste (o el resultado incorrecto). Así mismo, estas preguntas normalmente deberían llevar un ejemplo de la salida esperada. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu consulta es que estás agrupando tus ventas por bodega, pero luego no estás utilizando esa columna y la necesitas para hacer la relación correcta con otras tablas y así tener una llave única.

Le di un poco de formato a tu código para hacerlo más legible.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spRotacionFinal]
(
    @fi date,
    @ff date
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH Resumen as (
    SELECT dnv.id_producto,
           nv.id_bodega, 
           SUM(dnv.cantidad) Vendido
    FROM    DETALLE_NOTAVENTA dnv 
    JOIN    NOTA_VENTAS        nv on dnv.id_nota   = nv.id_nota
    WHERE   CONVERT( date, nv.fecha, 1) >= @fi
    and     CONVERT( date, nv.fecha, 1) <= @ff
    GROUP BY dnv.id_producto,
             nv.id_bodega
)
SELECT  e.id_producto as codigo,
        p.nombre as descripcion,
        e.id_local,
        b.nombre as bodega,
        e.Disponible as disponible,
        @fi as inicio,
        @ff as final,
        COALESCE(r.Vendido, 0) Vendido
FROM       EXISTENCIAS e
LEFT JOIN  Resumen     r ON e.id_producto = r.id_producto
                        AND e.id_local    = r.id_bodega
INNER JOIN BODEGAS     b ON e.Id_local    = b.id_local
INNER JOIN PRODUCTOS   p ON e.id_producto = p.id_producto
ORDER BY e.id_producto,
         e.id_local;

GO
```